# Converse Lagrange Theorem?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a non abelian group of order $12$, and $G \not \cong A_{4}$ Then $G$ contains an element of order $6$.

How can I prove it?

I know that the converse of Lagrange Theorem is not true for $A_4$ having an element of order $6$. And is true for all abelian Groups.

Any help, thanks.

Comment: basically what do u wanna ask? be specific?

Comment: @user312254 I think the question is sufficiently clear.

Comment: A group of order $12$ that is not isomorphic to $A_4$ has a normal Sylow $3$-subgroup $P = \langle t \rangle$. For any element $g \in G$, we have $gtg^{-1}=t$ or $t^{-1}$, so there must be some $g$ of order $2$ with $gtg^{-1}=t$ and then $gt$ has order $6$.